# Collapsed Menu Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a web page that is built using MVC and .NET Core 2. So this page is generated from Razor.

When I run the page in Visual Studio and shrink my page down so that the screen is narrower it collapses the menu, and the hamburger menu expands the options.

However when it is deployed to my web host, the menu stops working. It collapses down but when clicking it it does not expand.

Any ideas?

The web page is located at https://www.techsportise.com/Account/Login and the code is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Your Races - Techsportise - Free race timing for running clubs</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.min.css?v=kHvJwvVAK1eJLN4w8xygUR3nbvlLmRwi5yr-OuAO90E" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap-united.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap-table.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/Races"><img src="/img/logoorangesmall.png" alt="Techsportise Logo" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/Home/Help">Help</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/API">API</a></li>
                </ul>

                <form method="post" id="logoutForm" class="navbar-right" action="/Account/Logout">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <a title="Races" href="/Races">Your Races</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a title="Manage" href="/Manage/Index">Your Account</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar-nav">Log out</button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CfDJ8B_47xDwuwZKosoOrEvsIEc-7sACUmVXlDOlvKkWFf6tADFpx4HkVTmogPp-MODeiLleKz94PutshRuzq-Hb3iH-iPa86vzlYoBPig4JbC8_9oAWo8qaFCQGK4oXApQW1mmLKNAgFJs2jIJt7a2O8LA6eJiSShT5HxQ-VhHvspwn0YEOS6VoygnYCW331WEpjA" /></form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container body-content">
        <h2>Your Races</h2>
        <p>
            <a href="/Races/Create">New Race</a>
        </p>
        <form action="/Races" method="post">
            <p>
            <input type="text" name="searchString">
            <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
            </p>
            <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CfDJ8B_47xDwuwZKosoOrEvsIEc-7sACUmVXlDOlvKkWFf6tADFpx4HkVTmogPp-MODeiLleKz94PutshRuzq-Hb3iH-iPa86vzlYoBPig4JbC8_9oAWo8qaFCQGK4oXApQW1mmLKNAgFJs2jIJt7a2O8LA6eJiSShT5HxQ-VhHvspwn0YEOS6VoygnYCW331WEpjA" /></form>
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Race Director</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Phone Number</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Time</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center">Race Capacity</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center">Current Entries</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center">Entries</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center">Results</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center">Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="/Races/Details/1">My Race</a></td>
                        <td>My RD</td>
                        <td>rd@techsportise.com</td>
                        <td>01234 567890</td>
                        <td>04 June 2010</td>
                        <td>10:00</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">500</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">10</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center"><a href="/RaceEntries/List/1">Entries</a></td>
                        <td style="text-align: center"><a href="/Results/Details/1">Results</a></td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">
                            <a href="/Races/Edit/1"><img src="/img/edit.png" alt="edit" /></a>
                            <a href="/Races/Delete/1"><img src="/img/delete.png" alt="delete" /></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="/Races/Details/2">Andover 10k</a></td>
                        <td>Matthew Warr</td>
                        <td>matt@techsportise.com</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>24 November 2017</td>
                        <td>09:00</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">100</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">2</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center"><a href="/RaceEntries/List/2">Entries</a></td>
                        <td style="text-align: center"><a href="/Results/Details/2">Results</a></td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">
                            <a href="/Races/Edit/2"><img src="/img/edit.png" alt="edit" /></a>
                            <a href="/Races/Delete/2"><img src="/img/delete.png" alt="delete" /></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="/Races/Details/3">Hampshire Marathon</a></td>
                        <td>Matthew Warr</td>
                        <td>matt@techsportise.com</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>20 January 2018</td>
                        <td>09:30</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">5000</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center"><a href="/RaceEntries/List/3">Entries</a></td>
                        <td style="text-align: center"><a href="/Results/Details/3">Results</a></td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">
                            <a href="/Races/Edit/3"><img src="/img/edit.png" alt="edit" /></a>
                            <a href="/Races/Delete/3"><img src="/img/delete.png" alt="delete" /></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="/Races/Details/4">Balksbury Hill Climb</a></td>
                        <td>Matthew Warr</td>
                        <td>matt@techsportise.com</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>22 April 2018</td>
                        <td>10:00</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">12000</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center"><a href="/RaceEntries/List/4">Entries</a></td>
                        <td style="text-align: center"><a href="/Results/Details/4">Results</a></td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">
                            <a href="/Races/Edit/4"><img src="/img/edit.png" alt="edit" /></a>
                            <a href="/Races/Delete/4"><img src="/img/delete.png" alt="delete" /></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="/Races/Details/5">Valentines 5k</a></td>
                        <td>Matthew Warr</td>
                        <td>matt@techsportise.com</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>14 February 2018</td>
                        <td>07:30</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">150</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center"><a href="/RaceEntries/List/5">Entries</a></td>
                        <td style="text-align: center"><a href="/Results/Details/5">Results</a></td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">
                            <a href="/Races/Edit/5"><img src="/img/edit.png" alt="edit" /></a>
                            <a href="/Races/Delete/5"><img src="/img/delete.png" alt="delete" /></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="/Races/Details/6">Techsportise Half Marathon</a></td>
                        <td>string</td>
                        <td>string</td>
                        <td>string</td>
                        <td>26 November 2017</td>
                        <td>04:39</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center"><a href="/RaceEntries/List/6">Entries</a></td>
                        <td style="text-align: center"><a href="/Results/Details/6">Results</a></td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">
                            <a href="/Races/Edit/6"><img src="/img/edit.png" alt="edit" /></a>
                            <a href="/Races/Delete/6"><img src="/img/delete.png" alt="delete" /></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="/Races/Details/7">The Elite Race</a></td>
                        <td>Jon Warr</td>
                        <td>jon.mark.warr@gmail.com</td>
                        <td>07734190692</td>
                        <td>27 November 2017</td>
                        <td>05:00</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">20000</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">2</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center"><a href="/RaceEntries/List/7">Entries</a></td>
                        <td style="text-align: center"><a href="/Results/Details/7">Results</a></td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">
                            <a href="/Races/Edit/7"><img src="/img/edit.png" alt="edit" /></a>
                            <a href="/Races/Delete/7"><img src="/img/delete.png" alt="delete" /></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="/Races/Details/8">We Love Jodie 10k</a></td>
                        <td>Jodie Warr
                        </td><td>jodiewarr@hotmail.com</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>04 November 2018</td>
                        <td>11:35</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">100</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">2</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center"><a href="/RaceEntries/List/8">Entries</a></td>
                        <td style="text-align: center"><a href="/Results/Details/8">Results</a></td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">
                            <a href="/Races/Edit/8"><img src="/img/edit.png" alt="edit" /></a>
                            <a href="/Races/Delete/8"><img src="/img/delete.png" alt="delete" /></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="/Races/Details/9">Langport 10k</a></td>           


                        <td>Simon Smith</td>
                        <td>Sismith1@hotmail.co.uk</td>
                        <td>07515541144</td>
                        <td>28 November 2017</td>
                        <td>07:15</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">1</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">1</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center"><a href="/RaceEntries/List/9">Entries</a></td>
                        <td style="text-align: center"><a href="/Results/Details/9">Results</a></td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">
                            <a href="/Races/Edit/9"><img src="/img/edit.png" alt="edit" /></a>
                            <a href="/Races/Delete/9"><img src="/img/delete.png" alt="delete" /></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="/Races/Details/10">Chilly Hilly</a> </td>
                        <td>hgkjg</td>
                        <td>jkhgkjh@kygkjh.com</td>
                        <td>123</td>
                        <td>31 December 2017</td>
                        <td>11:59</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">200</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">0</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center"><a href="/RaceEntries/List/10">Entries</a></td>
                        <td style="text-align: center"><a href="/Results/Details/10">Results</a></td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">
                            <a href="/Races/Edit/10"><img src="/img/edit.png" alt="edit" /></a>
                            <a href="/Races/Delete/10"><img src="/img/delete.png" alt="delete" /></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

<hr />
<footer>
<div class="text-right">
<p><a href="/Home/About">About Us</a> | <a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a> | <a href="/Home/PrivacyPolicy">Privacy Policy</a> | <a href="/Home/Terms">Terms & Conditions</a></p>
</div>
<p>&copy; 2017 - Techsportise</p>
</footer>
</div>

<script src="/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/js/site.min.js?v=47DEQpj8HBSa-_TImW-5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap-table.js?v=JatmtP-zNtX22f6CZSAaTAiUbeE_OJM1rvbMenv-t6g"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You haven't included jQuery

Comment: If you open the browsers webdeveloper tool it will show errors in the console that jQuery is not defined just like @VilleKoo pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to VilleKoo and Orvar I found in my source that in Developer environment jquery was inlcuded but in production environment it wasn't. I have added it now.

**_layout.cshtml**

```
<environment include="Development">
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <script src="~/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        @*<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa">
        </script>*@
        <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        <script src="~/js/bootstrap-table.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>
```

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out :)

Answer (score 0):

I can not see the jQuery file.You can try to add.

> jquery-file.js <---

```
    <script src="/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/site.min.js?v=47DEQpj8HBSa-_TImW-5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap-table.js?v=JatmtP-zNtX22f6CZSAaTAiUbeE_OJM1rvbMenv-t6g"></script>
```